# Mediation: significant indirect effect but one path is not significant

Tags: causality, mediation

I ran a mediation analysis in PROCESS (Hayes, 2013) with one mediator. 
While path a was highly significant, path b was not (*p*=.193).  However the indirect effect was significant.

In this case, can I claim mediation?

Comment: What are the estimation results of a, b and indirect effect?

Comment: A path  B = .55, 
B path B = -.15, 
Indirect effect B = -.08

Comment: Your estimation results show that the magnitude of the indirect effect is even smaller than the magnitude of path b which is insignificant. How did you do the hypothesis testing for the indirect effect? The sampling distribution of the indirect effect estimate is not normally distributed. MacKinnon and colleagues have some papers on this topic, e.g. "A comparison of methods to test mediation and other intervening variable effects".

Comment: I used the bootstrap method (bias corrected, 5,000 re-samples) in PROCESS. Because the confidence interval did not involve zero, the indirect effect is significant. Isn't the indirect effect always smaller than one of the path a or b because it's a product of two terms <1 ?